# VSTO AddIn Suddenly Unable To Call External Methods

Tags: .net, vsto

I'm having a very baffling (and inconsistent) problem with a VSTO Outlook AddIn. In working on some upgrades, suddenly the AddIn seems to be unable to call code that is within a different class within the project itself. This isn't a referenced assembly or anything, just managed code found in a separate class file. 
The best way I was able to confirm this is adding an alert box as the very first line in the method being called.

In the main AddIn FormRegion:

```
Private Sub DocumentMenu_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DocumentMenu.Click

    Dim applicationName As String = "MyApp"
    Dim supportGroupName As String = "MyAppSupport"

    SetLoadingStatus("Validating user...") ' <<-- This works
    MsgBox("About to call the method") ' <<-- This works
    Dim userStatus As String = DocumentService.UserIsAuthorized ' <<-- Dies here
    If userStatus.ToUpperInvariant() = "Valid User".ToUpperInvariant() Then

        Me.SetLoadingStatus("Checking attachments...")
```

In DocumentService.vb:

```
Public Shared Function UserIsAuthorized() As String
    MsgBox("First line of method") '<< -- Doesn't ever come up
        Try
            Using handler As New RestServiceHandler
                Using client As HttpClient = handler.GetRestConfiguartion()
                ' Etc. - irreleveant because it never gets this far
```

The vexing thing is that I didn't change the code at all where this is happening. It doesn't happen all the time (it worked on my machine, my co-worker's machine as well as one testing machine, but not on the second or on my end users' machines).

I am local admin on my machine, but not on either of the testing machines (including one where it worked). It has failed on both Win7/Office 2010 and Win10/Office 2016 machines. (All the machines where it works have Win10/Office 2016, and most of our clients do too.) It has failed using both OneClick distribution as well as signed .msi installers.

I did update the .Net framework from 4.0 to 4.6.2, but even when I roll it back to 4.0 I still see this behavior. There is a version in production on 4.0 that works for 270 users, including one for whom the new version didn't work. Our end-users' machined are pretty locked down, so my debugging options are fairly limited. On the one test machine where I can replicate this behavior, I don't see any errors logged in Event Viewer.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this? To the best that I'm able to determine, it just simply dies before it can invoke the code in a different class file within the same project.

**Edit**: One thing I don't think I made clear - the AddIn itself loads without error. There is code that executes to pull the current environment from a config file and that executes without issue. The error seems to happen on a button click event which shows a region of the form after checking user authorization.

Also, I took the UserIsAuthorized method and added it to the same .vb file as the button click event, and the error still occurs. It's like the app is unable to call code in another method no matter where in the project that method is found, which just seems baffling to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the past there was an issue with competing addins. If one addin needed a different version of .Net than the other, the first one loaded would win, while the other one would fail. Depending on the version of office, this could happen because the office app only ran one version of .Net, not multiples.

Check for other addins on the failure pcs and disable; that might provide the answer.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that. FYI I added an edit with some more stuff I've been trying. But I will take note as best I can on the machines where it's not working right.

Comment: So I tried uninstalling any other AddIns and it didn't seem to fix the issue.